# Setup network between VMs using tap network with Nix?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, nixos, nix

I'm trying to have a network shared between multiple VMs.

I've tried adding:

```
    qemu.networkingOptions = [
                               "-nic user,model=virtio-net-pci"
                               "-netdev tap,id=mynet0"
                             ];
```

However this results in an error of:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: network script /etc/qemu-ifup failed with status 256
```

Even when running as root. Also I don't see where this file actually is located? Would this be on the guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the option purity. I mean you cannot mix network declaration

```
-net nic,model=virtio-net-pci,macaddr=... -net user,restrict=[on|off]
```

with

```
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=...  -netdev tap,ifname=tap0,id=net0,script=...,downscript=...
```

where the first option create virtual LAN of private range 10.0.0.x/8 giving a DHCP addres 10.0.0.15 to the guest VM and (dis)allow the guest VM to go through an embeded NAT firewall to the host system network; 
while the letter option shown creates a virtual interface bind with tap0 interface of the host machine, where you should define to which real interface the tap0 is connected.

Hence if you want to connect two VM, let's say VMA/tapA and VMB/tapB , you can connetct those VMs together through a bridge which can be defined for example with:

```
# ip link add name brAB type bridge
# ip link set dev  brAB up
# ip link set dev  tapA master brAB
# ip link set dev  tapB master brAB
# ip link set dev  tapA up
# ip link set dev  tapB up
```

This configuration creates isolated network connecting VMA and VMB **only!**. To make this network binded with some free host NIC or config an other networking schemas you have to read more about the network configuration of the real host machine e.g. about vitual swith (openvswitch) or other possibilities.

Ofcourse, the dummy interface tapA or tapB need to be crated before you try to use them. You can do it for example with:

```
# ip tuntap add name tapA mode tap
```

command.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the following:

```
qemu.networkingOptions = [
                           "-device e1000,netdev=abc,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01"
                           "-netdev tap,id=abc,ifname=tapA,script=no,downscript=no"
                         ];
```

And in the second vm changing the address + interface:

```
qemu.networkingOptions = [
                           "-device e1000,netdev=abc,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:02"
                           "-netdev tap,id=abc,ifname=tapB,script=no,downscript=no"
                         ];
```

As mentioned by @schweik I also needed to configure the network which I used the following script for:

```
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    --down)
        ip link delete brAB
        ip link delete tapA
        ip link delete tapB
    ;;
    --up)

        ip link add name brAB type bridge
        ip link set dev brAB up

        ip tuntap add dev tapA mode tap user $(whoami)
        ip tuntap add dev tapB mode tap user $(whoami)

        ip link set dev tapA master brAB
        ip link set dev tapB master brAB
        ip link set dev tapA up
        ip link set dev tapB up
    ;;
esac
done
```